# Cloning of a project from Git to Intellij using HTTPS not working

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup Intellij for a project from github repository. While trying to clone the repo, it gives the following error :

unable to access 'https://github.com/petro-it/x.git/': Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT

I know this is related to server issue, FYI, server is working fine and credentials too.

Comment: "404" = "not found": the server claims not to know anything about the URL you're presenting. Either you're presenting the wrong URL and/or to the wrong server, or the server doesn't like you, so figure out which of these is the case and go from there. Are you really reaching github.com, or are you reaching some other server? If you are reaching github.com, what credentials are you presenting *to* GitHub?

Comment: At the Git level, consider using GIT_TRACE, GIT_TRACE2, and GIT_PACKET_TRACE. At the libcurl level, consider setting CURL tracing. Search for each of these terms if necessary.

Comment: does the repo exist? do you have permissions to access the repo? are you authenticated?

Comment: @knittl Yes, The repo exist and I do have permission to the repo, I m able to access and even modify as and when required through github gui. I am logged in to the github through Intellij, The repo does show up in Intellij, just the clone part fails,.

Comment: @torek, The Url is coped from Github itself and pasted in Intellij,  I m able to access and even modify as and when required through github gui. The credentials are just good, I am properly logged in, I have tried through the token as well.

Comment: And yet, the clone is failing with "404 not found". So: sure, it's right. It's also wrong. Use the tools I suggested using above to figure out *why* it's wrong for the case(s) when it is wrong. You might also look into doing some low level packet tracing with hardware or software (e.g., tcpdump/wireshark).